# Select table cell using class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

Is there a way I can select table cell by using 'class' used on the cell. Well example is better than 1000 words...

How can I select elements using javascript to select `.redcell` only in the table? I need to insert function for every td separately, so `td .redcell` is not a solution as well as the indexes.

```css
.redcell {background-color: red}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="redcell">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td class="redcell">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="redcell">don't select me</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through each elements that contains redcell class, you should use delegation. In that case, you don't need to add another event listener for dynamically added `<td>` and also, the code looks cleaner.

Add click event listener to one of the ancestor element of `<td>`. Here, the ancestor element can be `<table>`. When you click a `<td>`, the click event handler will get called. Find the clicked element information by event.target and if event.target is `<td>` and has redcell class,then perform your logic.

See this [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pa6y8gmd/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `querySelectorAll()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/697/)

```js
var cell = document.querySelectorAll('table td.redcell');
for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
  cell[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

Update: You can `addEventListener` to each cell like this

```js
var cell = document.querySelectorAll('table td.redcell');
cell[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.color = 'red';
});

cell[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.color = 'green';
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="redcell">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="redcell">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="redcell">don't select me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I already tried that and its not what I want, because it selects everything using "redcell" class. But my goal is to make every cell using "redcell" class 'unique'. Every cell with "redcell" will have different function.

Comment: This selects every `td` with class `redcell`, also what do you mean by different function?

Comment: From code above: redcell which contains '3' will have onclick option to change to blue and redcell containing '2' will have onclick function to turn pink for example.

Comment: You should state that in your question

Comment: You can then access each individual cell like this `cell[0]` and addEventListener like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/700/

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted! :) But when I add another <td> redcell above these ones it will mess up right? :/ Any chance to make the cell unique, like cell containing 3 will be selector(table td .redcell.indexOf("3") or something like it

Comment: You could assign unique id to every cell with class redcell and then you can select them by id, also you must append new content before this selection so it should look like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/712/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use the following selector to select only td elements with the redcell class:

```
$("td.redcell")
```

Its equivalent in pure JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td.redcell');
```

Comment: pure js only please.